# Connecting to RDS Postgres from remote machine

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services

I have configured an RDS Postgres micro instance for testing but am having problem connecting. I have created a security group and allow all hosts (0.0.0.0/0) by default to port 5432 but for some reason I am not able to connect. I tried connecting to the port 5432 on the machine but it appears to be closed. Any ideas? I have verified that the security group is using the correct security group.

This is my configuration

```
TCP
Port (Service)  Source  Action
5432    0.0.0.0/0   Delete
```

Here is how I am trying to connect to the rds service

```
psql -p 5432 -h example.cs945smhrv09.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com -U example example
```

**UPDATE**

OK feel a little silly after figuring out that rds starts up on a private 172 subnet. I was able to connect from my ec2 instance.

Question now is there a way to put that on a public address that I can connect to? I would like to configure it with a security group that limits the source ip but then be able to connect to it with psql from my desktop.

**Update 2**

I don't remember all the details when I originally posted this question but it is no longer an issue. We now have a management vpc that we connect to using a vpn server. The management vpc network is trusted by the prod and devel security groups for the rds instances. We have no problem communicating with them without adding any public ips.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Step 4 of the RDS setup wizard ("Additional Config") lets you select whether the DB is Publicly Accessible or not (if it's not, access is limited to within your VPC, regardless of your security group settings). I'd imagine that determines whether the hostname resolves to 54.* vs 172.* .

Your first instance may have been set to private - as far as I can tell this can't be changed after initialization. I had a similar issue and creating a new instance set to be publicly accessible solved it for me.

Comment: This answer is almost 4 years old so it may not have been possible at the time, but today you can change your RDS instance from public to private if you go into the Modify menu of the instance. There's a radio button there to toggle Public on or off, which you can then apply immediately or during the next maintenance window

Answer (score 14):

My company's firewall had blocked outgoing traffic to the default postgres port, 5432.  I didn't realise this until I tested the port using netcat in a terminal window, as follows:

```
nc -zv portquiz.net 5432
```

Hopefully this saves someone half a day of messing around with AWS security groups.

Answer (score 4):

Absolutely there is. I have pgadmin loaded on my local machine connected to my RDS instance. |

I just confirmed that I can connect using the same syntax you used for psql, although the -U was not necessary for me (I still included both "example" parameters though)

I did edit the "default" security group and added my IP (Ip of the machine I'm connecting from)/32 to be allowed, although I'm sure you could get less restrictive than that, but I'd start there and see if it helps.

Comment: Hey Joe, I tried that but the problem is that the RDS instance does not have a public ip address. It is on a private network. Not sure where I configure it to have a public adddress. I am now familiar with the vcp security groups as it is very much like iptables in linux. I have configured it to allow from any host but still cannot connect to it. I am only able to connect from the ec2 interface. I think there is some kind of configuration I have to do in order to give it a public routable ip address. When I ping the host from a remote system it resolves to the 172.* address but my ec2 is 54.*

Comment: This is very odd because mine resolves to a 52.* address -- I have a experimental server "primoweb.c1seoysgtur3.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com" (my actual servers name in aws) .. check that it resolves to a 54 address. I did nothing special and don't pay of an IP address either. I checked through my settings and I see no way to turn on or off the public ip address.

Comment: Actually, your machine likely has a NAT address, but it should resolve given the domain name though.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely caused by your outbound firewall rules. If you're behind a corporate firewall, they will often block outbound ports above a certain number. You need to setup an SSH tunnel of some kind to avoid this.
http://conoroneill.net/accessing-amazon-rds-instances-from-your-desktop/

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. This isn't a direct solution but might work for some. I set the Postgres security group to accept connections coming from the server that will be using it (same VPC). I then set up my Postgres client to use ssh tunneling. If I need to use the command line, I simply SSH into that server and then `psql` from there.

Answer (score -2):

You can simply use workbench recommended by aws but make sure your all postgres availibily is set to  everywhere..while adding PostgrSQL 5432

https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/tutorials/create-connect-postgresql-db/